# Theorem 2.1.4 in Durrett's Probability Theory and Examples

Tags: probability, measure-theory, independence

I am reading Durrett's *Probability Theory and Examples* proof of Theorem 2.1.4.

Theorem 2.1.4: In order for $X_1, \dots, X_n$ to be independent, it is sufficient that for all $x_1, \dots, x_n \in (-\infty, \infty]$ that $P(X_1 \leq x_1, \dots, X_n \leq x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n P(X_i \leq x_i)$.

Proof: Let $\mathcal{A}_i$ = sets of the form $\{X_i \leq x_i\}$. [... (showing that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\pi$-system)] Since we have allowed $x_i = \infty, \Omega \in \mathcal{A}_i$. [...] $\sigma(\mathcal{A}_i) = \sigma(X_i)$, so the result follows from Theorem 2.1.3 (which states that if $\pi$-systems $\mathcal{A}_1 \dots \mathcal{A}_n$ are independent, then the sigma-algebras generated by each of them are independent).

My question is why do we need $\Omega \in \mathcal{A}_i$? The only condition for Theorem 2.1.3 is that each set is a $\pi$-system, which only requires that $\mathcal{A}_i$ to be closed under intersection. Further, the $\sigma(\cdot)$ operation already "adds" in an $\Omega$. Could someone please explain why is this sentence/step necessary? Thanks a lot!